How to import AWS Lambda Layers in a Multi-Lambda Python Project locally?
I need help setting up imports for a multi-Lambda project that utilizes AWS Lambda Layers. Here's my current project structure:
/
├── pyproject.toml
└── lambdas/
    ├── function1/
    │   ├── requirements.txt
    │   ├── handler.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── function2/
    │   ├── requirements.txt
    │   ├── handler.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── layers/
        └── shared/
            └── python/
                ├── config/
                ├── constants/
                └── utils/

In my function1/handler.py file locally, I'm importing from a shared layer. For instance, to import config, I currently use:
import lambdas.layers.shared.python.config

However, when I deploy this to AWS Lambda, this import path isn't available because I'm packaging only what's inside function1/ for the Lambda, and shared/python as a layer, following AWS Docs.
The root of the deployed Lambda looks like this with the layer:
requirements.txt
handler.py
__init__.py

I want to be able to import config locally without errors, similar to how it would work in the deployed Lambda, like this:
import config

How can I achieve this setup? I'm using a single virtual environment for the entire project managed by Poetry.
